# Regex to catch ANY non-letter, non-number, non-space

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I am trying to allow ONLY letters numbers and spaces.

no _  . ! ~ `

and any other special character (i know that _ is supposed to be letter.. i just dont want it)

my question is: how should i write it?

mostly ive found answeres that specified the characters that are "illegal" like:

```
^[^$&+,:;=?@}{#|'\\<>\/.^*()%!\]\[~`_-]+[^$&+,:;=?@}{#|'\\<>\/.^*()%!\]\[~`_-]*$
```

but i was wondering if theres a better way to do it like :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+[a-zA-z0-9\s]*$
```

the problem with this  one is that if the characters  ``` []^``_\ ``` are after letter/number/space its still passes thru

```
[]`\^_    <<this will be illegal
1[]`\^_    <<this will not be caught as illegal
```

I also tried:`^[\w\d\s]+[\w\d\s]*$`

but it lets _  go thru

edit
i had a typo in the second code (A-z) so changed it to

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$
```

and it works perfectly

so is it better to write like this instead of typing everysingle special chatacter (like the first code)?
are there possible characters that could slip by this check?

Comment: Is the `A-z` a typo in your second pattern or actually there? It might be the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Look at the definition of `\w`, then rewrite its expansion  without the underscore

Comment: @SebastianProske it **is** the reason

Comment: Also, `[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*` is pointless after `[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+`

Comment: @SebastianProske is correct, the "A-z" definition include all characters in the "A" to "z" character and it include then all the special character between "Z" and "a", so bcampolo answer is correct : only space, alpha and number with at least one caracter. for the caracters range, take a look at the ASCII table or Unicode Map depending on the regexp parsing mode.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question well, you can use a negated character class to do this. For instance, match all characters that are NOT letters:

```
[^A-Za-z]+
```

You can use anchors to match lines that contains only letters

```
^[^A-Za-z]+$
```

If you consider spaces or whitespaces (`\s`) as valid, just add it to the character class:

```
^[^A-Za-z\s]+$
```

Related to the "best" approach, you can compare the performance for sure, but what the best way if the performance has not a big impact, imho is the most readable expression.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work (corrected/simplified version of your example above)

If you want to include all letters (upper or lower) and any number and just the space character:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

If you want to any whitespace:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$
```

Comment: space **!=** `\s`

Comment: I know \s is not the same as space, but SpiderPool's question said "spaces".  Please re-read the question before down-voting me.

Comment: IMHO, *spaces* is larger than *whitespace*, it includes `\t` for example

Comment: In Java (which SpiderPool tagged this question as), the actual space character inside a regex [ ] does not include \t or any other whitespace.  It is literally only the space character.  The following example will print "false".  System.out.println("Test this \t regex".matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$"));  Either way, not worth a down-vote.